# how to install driver for intel extreme graphics 2

Tags: linux-device-driver, ubuntu-11.10

I installed Linux on an Intel Panel PC. Jockey cannot detect any drivers. I do not know how to install my graphics driver first so that I am be able to install touch screen.

Here's some info from `dmesg`:

dmesg | grep vga

```
[    0.254052] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.254082] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.254088] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[   13.506146] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem

# dmesg | grep -i controller

[    0.411625] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    1.109132] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.109226] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.128532] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.128569] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.128674] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.129311] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.129930] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.130580] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.131337] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
```

As I searched more, I think the graphics driver is installed by default, but I have no idea how I can check it availability in my system.
sound driver is installed correctly.

Comment: I guess superuser is a better aite for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check state of driver in kernel, if it implemented as "kernel object" = .ko file with command "lsmod". If it wasn't loaded in kernel, you can load it manually with command "insmod mod_name_with_path".
You can also set automatic load your driver at system startup with command "echo mod_name_with_path >/proc/sys/kernel/modprobe".
There is useful info about lkm (kernel objects): http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/